# Does shrinking making space available to partitions everywhere?

Tags: windows-server-2008, hard-drive, diskmanagement, partition

In Disk Management for Windows 2008, I have an extended partition that looks like this:

|----X:\ Drive----||----Y:\ Drive----||-------Z:\ Drive-------|

I am running out of space for the Y: drive. I have a lot of space I can spare in the Z: drive. If I shrink the Z: drive, will the space be available to extend the Y: drive? Or will the empty space only be for any drives that come after the Z: drive?

I wish there was some kind of preview to this, so I am asking for help.

Comment: I *think* but I'm not sure, that extending only works to the right. In other words, the space will be available for a new partition only.

Answer (score 1):

Partition managers like [gparted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/) let you expand the disk space in either direction.  Because this is the standard behavior for partitioning, its a safe assumption that Windows 2008 Disk Manager does the same.  If you scale the the first block of your `Z:\` drive to the right, those blocks to the right of `Y:\` now become available.  Visually...

```
|----X:\ Drive----||----Y:\ Drive----||>>-----Z:\ Drive-------|

|----X:\ Drive----||----Y:\ Drive----||--free--||--Z:\ Drive--|

|----X:\ Drive----||---------Y:\ Drive---------||--Z:\ Drive--|
```

Hope this helps!  I believe the W2k8 Disk Manager will give you a "preview" of what's going to happen before it actually writes the changes to the partition table.  [Microsoft TechNet seems to agree with me](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733060.aspx).

Good luck, and remember that backing up should be the first thing you do! ;)